# Error with matplotlib when used with Unicode strings

Tags: python, numpy, unicode, matplotlib

I have text file  containing Unicode strings and their frequencies.

```
അംഗങ്ങള്‍ക്ക്    10813
കുടുംബശ്രീ   10805
പരിരക്ഷാപദ്ധതിക്ക്   10778
ചെയ്തു   10718
ഇന്ന്‌   10716
അന്തര്‍     659
രാജിന്റെ    586
```

When I try to plot it using `matplotlib`

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot.py", line 3, in <module>
    xs, ys = np.loadtxt('oun.txt', delimiter='\t').T
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 841, in loadtxt
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '
```

This is the code I have

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xs, ys = np.loadtxt('oun.txt', delimiter='\t').T
plt.bar(xs, ys)
plt.show()
```

Whats wrong with this code ?

Comment: 'matplotlib' instead of 'matplolib' and 'plt.bar' instead of 'pplt.bar' ? or are those just typos here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to read strings from a file using `loadtxt` you have to specify the `dtype` argument (see [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) here).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('derp', dtype={'names': ('strings', 'freq'),
                                   'formats': ('S32', 'i4')})

xs, ys = zip(*data)
temp = range(len(ys)) # Temp variable for use as x-axis.

plt.bar(temp, ys, align='center')
plt.xticks(temp, xs) # Re-define ticks as your strings.

plt.show()
```

In this case the file has 2 columns, I've given them the `names` `('strings', 'freq')` and the `formats` are `('S32', 'i4')` where `S` denotes a string and `i` denotes an integer. The docs for `dtype` can be found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html). Note that the numbers within the `dtype` formatting give information on the size of the values in your columns (`i4` corresponds to a 32-bit signed integer for example).